# Make parent div contain all space of child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, containers

My parent container is to small to contain my child div.

This is parent div.
[image: parent]

This is child div
[image: child]

As you can see i get bad layout.

Very similar example to my code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/buz72ck5/

Part of code :

```
<div class="space-container">
    <div class="space-main-data">
        <ul>
            <li>sp1</li>
            <li>59000</li>
            <li>20000</li>
            <li></li>
            <li style="float: right">
                <input type="hidden" value="355646" class="lease-space-id"><span>Available</span>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="additional-space-data-wrapper">
    <div class="additional-space-data">
        <dl class="ld-generalinfo-wrap ld-main-info">
            <dt>Date Available:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Term Range:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd><strong>1-30</strong></dd>

            <dt>Lease Type:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Rental Rate Range:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Maximum Contiguous:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Dock High:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Minimum Divisible:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Drive In:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Office Space:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Clear Height:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt></dt>
            <dd></dd>

            <dt>Column Spacing:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>               

            <dt>Rail:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Yard:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>                             

            <dt>Power:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>

            <dt>Truck Court:&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd class="unlisted-value"><strong>Unlisted</strong></dd>        
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.additional-space-data, .left-space-group` is `position: absolute;` which takes it out of the document flow, removing that may do the trick although your code could do with a bit of a general tidy up.

Comment: Yes I think @HiddenHobbes is correct - there's no need for that "additional-space-data" block to be `position: absolute;` (and it makes no sense to have both that and `float: left;` anyway).

Comment: @HiddenHobbes and @Pointy, thanks, and if i set for `.space-container` style `display:inline-block` will it be good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside this `.additional-space-data-wrapper` element is another with `position:Absolute`  taking that outside of the flow document then his `height` is `0`.

But wait if you remove that `position` the element `additional-space-data` is still floated on the parent and then his height = `0` you will need to clear also the float.

Try this:

```
.additional-space-data {
   float: left;
   /*position:Absolute REMOVE THIS*/   
   width: 55%;
}
.additional-space-data-wrapper:after {
  display:table;
  content:" ";
  clear:both;
}
```

Check this [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buz72ck5/2/)

Comment: Thanks! And can you tell me what difference will be if i set instead of `display : table` - `display : inline-block`? For me ther are no difference on UI, but maybe in some cases there are some difference

Comment: In this case I just use the value table on display since pseudo-elements needs that property to exist....But on structures an layouts `table` or inline-block can suit many different needs ... inline-block wraps --- table don't --- table takes entire height on all childs --- inline-block not @demo

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I removed everything from .space-container {}

You'll have to fiddle with the width and there is only one item in the Column Spacing but at least everything is now on one line.

```
.space-container {   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/l0nd0n/txyq4v1x/

Comment: if you add one more `space-container` you will get "onlay". In my case `space-container`-s can be more then 1